# what size should gas grill burner flames be

Tags: gas, outdoor, backyard

i have a charbroil 'red' grill. it used to get very hot. now I  hold my hand over cooking surface for 5 to 10 seconds. not good.

yes i tried to reset the regulator based on most internet suggestions

i see nice blue flames coming out of the tiny holes but they are only about 1/4 to 3/8 inch in length . moving knobs from low ot high seems to have this small effect.

yes, there is a hairline crack on the gas tube (its acts like extra holes i guess in that blue flame comes out of that too)

Should there be much larger flames at high setting?

Comment: I find spiders where the air mixes after the valves all the time that cause these problems. There may be a wire mesh screen to try and keep them out but blockages in that area is usually the source of the problem for me. A crack in the gas tube ? I agree with mike below, a crack in a cast iron burner may not be a big issue but on a supply  line it should be replaced.

Comment: i think there must be some high temp epoxy that i can use to fix that manifold crack?       also , can you give me some sense of how 'big' the flames should be when i have this thing turned up to '11' :)    i have nothing to use as a reference. flames are nice and blue and maybe 3/8 inch long coming out of the manifold holes

Answer (score 1):

A hairline crack? which also burns gas?

So you should **STOP** using this at once, it is **NOT** safe.

Get it repaired by a competent person.

Comment: The crack is the metal manifold where the gas jets are. I dont understand why this is dangerous? It just acts like a few extra "holes". I see blue flame there equivalent to 2 or 3 normal holes.  think about it ... the gas doesnt know whether its coming out of the pinholes made in the factory or out of that pin hole made by mother nature :) 

What am I missing?

Regarding flame size...does 1/4 inch flames sound too small?